# how to access/create a .txt file with a "relative" path

Tags: c#, file, c#-4.0, filenotfoundexception

I'm creating an app that can take a text from one file, read it, edit the text via a string, then write the edited string in a new text file.

My problem is that the file can't be found. In the following example I placed the file in the folder indicated in the screenshot and in another attempt in the 'bin' file, both without success and identical error message.

What I was trying to a achieve is the the following (as I am aware I could write the whole path from "C:\"), the text file should be somewhere in the application's directory so that the whole app can be moved without having to re-write the path.

So I need a way to write a "relative" path, if such thing is possible. this should pls work with creating a file similarly as well.

[screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS2mz.png)

[visual studio screenshot with code and file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saVmh.png)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't post external links, instead embed all the images and the code sections inside your question (especially the code!).

Comment: About the relative path, what have you tried so far? What code have you written? Have you googled "c# relative path"? There are dozens of tutorials on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summary / Explanation**: The file is not found because the directory you have set is not the directory of the file. If the file is in the same directory as to the C# file you are currently working on, then there's no need to add a folder's directory into it but rather just type the filename. You can also consider what's written below this paragraph.

---

FIRST:
Click InputText.txt

SECOND:
Right Click and Choose "Properties" or just press Alt + Enter

THIRD: 
Set the "Build Action" property to "Embedded Resource"

FOURTH: 
Set the "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy always"

LASTLY: 
Change the Readline's first parameter to -> @"InputText.txt"

```
...
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"InputText.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
    {
       originalTextInLines.Add(line);
    }
...
```

---

[image: Accessing a Text File with a relative path]

This is the sample output (in my case of trying this).

[image: The text file the example application above reads]

This is the file that the example application above

[image: The output directory of the]

The file is in the same directory the Program.cs is found that the file may be addressed by typing its filename only.